# Error in Confusion Matrix :The data contain levels not found in the data

Tags: r, matrix, prediction, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I am cross-validating malware families with R caret. I am now trying to generate a confusion matrix and I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in confusionMatrix.default(crossval[[3]][[1]], data_train[, 1]) : 
The data contain levels not found in the data.
```

Here is my code:

```
#setwd("Malware/")
library(caret)
library(klaR)
library(randomForest)
# load the iris dataset
malware        <- read.table('C:/Users/awais/Desktop/Malware/1.csv',sep=",",header=TRUE)
malware = na.omit(malware)
malware$labels <- as.factor(malware$labels)
# define an 80%/20% train/test split of the dataset
split=0.80
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(malware$labels, p=split, list=FALSE)
data_train <- malware[ trainIndex,]
data_test  <- malware[-trainIndex,]

# Perform Cross Validation 
crossval <- rfcv(data_train[,2:1025],data_train[,1],cv.fold=2, do.trace=TRUE, ntree=100)

# print out OOB error result for number of features
print(crossval[[2]])

# get the resulting confusion matrix for the cross validation
results <- confusionMatrix(crossval[[3]][[1]],data_train[,1])
write.table(results[[2]],file="predict_crossval.csv",sep=",")
```

Comment: Please submit (a subset of)  the data, so that the example is reproducible.

Comment: I suspect that it is just what the error message says - The test data contain levels not found in the training data.   Try `table(data_train[,1])`  and `table(data_test[,1])` .    Are the possible results the same?

Comment: Just to be clear,  when I say "the same"  I mean are the lists of possible values the same.  Of course the counts will not be the same.

Comment: the data cannot have more levels than the reference.This is exact error.I got after running this program..